# Browserify produces a *huge* output file

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

With the aid of [node-google](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-google) module I wrote a simple node module to enable a 'text web search' feature to my web app, presenting results in one of my views.
Since after a quite small number of queries from the same IP Google returns a 503 error, I decide to use the module on the client, so the limit is per client, not per server.
I did use [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) to convert the node module to a script to be sourced in a client page.
The script just requires 'google.js', and it's just 20 lines of javascript long:

```
'use strict';
var google = require('google');

var Google = Object.create({});
var Google.search = function(text, callback) {
    ...
});
// end of the script
```

The command I use is simply:

```
  $ browserify google-search-module.js -o app/scripts/google-search.js
```

The problem is that the output browserify produces is **far** bigger than I did expect: a 1.2 kB module becomes a 2.4 MB script! Probably it's including all 'google' dependencies, too, but..,

The question is: is this normal? Is my search page expected to load a 2.4 MB file just to search some text on Google?

I'm quite sure I'm missing something, but can't understand what... :-(

Comment: Aside from the size (which probably _is_ caused by the dependencies), does it actually work from a browser?

Comment: I have no reason to doubt it actually works in the browser.., but, I didn't even test it: this is a secondary issue, given the size of the file. However, if this can help, I'll try soon and report it here.

Comment: If you can't get it to work in a browser to begin with, the large size won't be an issue anymore, I'd think :D

Comment: UPDATE: you were right: it doesn't work... :-( Switching to a client-side google scrape module...

Answer (score 2):

That is expected behaviour. [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) loads all modules imported with `require()` recursively, and outputs a single file. There are ways around this, but they are unlikely to work in your paticular case.

Normally, with Browserify, you might work with one huge bundle in development, but then build a much smaller production version. If you were using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), for example, you could install the package locally into your `node_modules` folder. Then, for production, you could set the [`--exclude`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) flag to have Browserify ignore anything in your `node_modules` folder, instead relying on a [CDN](https://jquery.com/download/#jquery-39-s-cdn-provided-by-maxcdn) to deliver jQuery to the client.

I say this is unlikely to work in your case because [node-google](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-google) really is a Node module. There is no guarantee that it will work in the browser (it may or may not). You really should determine if it is working before you start planning your next line of attack.

If it is working, you have two possible remedies:

1. Minify your bundle and make sure it is served gzipped. The resulting file size will likely be fewer than 100kB, if you can live with that.
2. Find some other module for doing a Google search, or implement one of your own. This is probably the best solution unless you must use node-google for some reason.

Of course, if it isn't working in the browser anyway, only the second solution is available.

Comment: Minified and gzipped? In my experience, minification alone would probably take it down to 700kB or so, and the gzipping should do the rest. I might be wrong, but in any case, the asker will find out if they choose that route.

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot about gzipping and did not notice you mentioned that explicitly, my apologies.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it in the browser for sure ASAP... I didn't even know about possible issues with 'browserified' node modules... :-( About jQuery exclusion, I don't think is a great improvement, on production I'll have my code on a CDN, too...

Comment: @MarcoS The point about serving common libraries from popular CDNs is that, most of the time, it will be served from the user's cache, so they won't have to download the library at all. If you bundle everything together, they will have to download the whole thing, even if most of it is already on their computer. So you should consider it.